# I need an idiom that means "be cool"/relax

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I just need something that connotes calming down from an exaggerated state. The next line afterwards is "I am cool" so I don't want the preceding line to be "be cool" but I want to convey the same thing. Something like "chill out" is good but I don't like that particular one for some reason.

Comment: Take it easy!!! https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/take-it-easy

Comment: Just a point.  If someone responds with “I *am* cool.” It’s usually because they were told to “*Be* cool.”   In other words: a response usually echos wording in the command.

Comment: What was wrong with "Relax!" mentioned in the title?

Comment: "Get hip and get on my tracks
Take a back seat, hitchhike
And take a long ride on my motorbike
Until I'm ready
Crazy little thing called love"

Comment: @Jim, that depends on emphasis. "I *am* cool" and "I am *cool*". "Don't be so hot-headed" could yield "I am *cool*".